# Interacting with the actionbar when using reflection

Tags: android, reflection, android-actionbar

In order to keep backwards compatibility I've created a class to access the action bar:

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

```
public class ReflectionBar{

    static void getActionBar(Activity a) {

        ActionBar bar = a.getActionBar();

        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(new TabListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }));


    bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    // remove the activity title to make space for tabs
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    return;
    }

}
```

And I call it in my Activity class using:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>10){
    ReflectionBar bar = new ReflectionBar();
    bar.getActionBar(this);
}
```

The problem is that I need to listen to the calls of onTabSelected in my main activity, but I am not sure how to set it up. I've tried a few different things with no success, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I need to listen to the calls of onTabSelected in my main activity, but I am not sure how to set it up. I've tried a few different things with no success, any help much appreciated.

Define an interface. Pass an instance of the interface into `getActionBar()` as a `final` parameter (which really ought to be named `initActionBar()`, since you're not returning an action bar, but, that's just me...). In the various `onTab...` methods in your `TabListener` objects, call a corresponding method on your interface. You won't be able to pass the `ActionBar.Tab` object to the interface (since that's API Level 11+), but between the tag and text properties, you should be able to glean something worth passing that identifies the tab to the activity.